# Bash function comment extraction from sourced file

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with functions I have sourced from a random file, that I no longer retain the original path.

```
#!/bin/bash
my_awesome_function()
{
   #- Usage: my_awesome_function <key> <to> <success>
   echo "I'm doing something great."
}
declare -x -f my_awesome_function
```

I have previously ran:

```
$ source ./some_random_file_i_dont_know_where_it_is
```

And followed up with (in the same shell):

```
$ type my_awesome_function

   my_awesome_function is a function
   my_awesome_function ()
   { 
       echo "I'm doing something great."
   }
```

I'm asking because I would like to include automated usage for this function. In the ideal case:

```
  exceptional_help()
  {
    echo ; type $1 | grep "#-" | tr -d "#-"
  }
```

Which could be used like follows:

```
  $ exceptional_help "my_awesome_function"

    Usage: my_awesome_function <key> <to> <success>
```

I have tried `type` and `declare` and `which` and a few other builtins, but nothing seems to retain the original formatting including comments, or a reference to the original function that I could then parse again.

Comment: Comments are ignored during parsing of the script, they're not saved in the function anywhere.

Comment: How can you not have the original path? Can't you just read the `source` command from your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
my_awesome_function() {
  [ "$1" = "--help" ] && { 
     echo 'Usage: my_awesome_function <key> <to> <success>'
     return
  }
  echo "I'm doing something great."
}
```

Example:

```
$ my_awesome_function 
I'm doing something great.
$ my_awesome_function --help
Usage: my_awesome_function <key> <to> <success>
```

Comment: He can't modify the function definition. Somehow he doesn't know where the function was sourced from.

Comment: @Barmar If that interpretation is correct, then he is in a pickle, isn't he?

Comment: Yes, he is. I said as much in my comment above.

Comment: This isn't what I originally had in mind, but this seems like its going to be much easier to implement than some kind of Arg parsing and dynamic substitution when sourcing the file

Answer (score 0):

In practice, it would be much more reliable to follow @John1024's solution. In its entirety if you can. I wrote a small wrapper around the source functionality that will extract specific comments for docs. That borrows the easy way to write a help string.

For future reference here is a macro orientated approach.

I couldn't quite get sourcing to work from stdin on BSD and bash 4, but I'm sure it is achievable without an intermediary file.

It also did need an additional replacement to close the brackets and this doesn't play nice with multi-line usage strings.

Random file:

```
my_awesome_function(){
  #--Usage : hello <arg1> <arg2> ++#
  echo "I'm doing something great."
  echo "and I'm totally self documented."
}
```

Custom sourcing :

```
self_documenting_source(){
  local src tmpfile
  src=$1
  tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/source.XXXXXX)
  < $src \
    sed 's/#--/[ "$1" == "--help" ] \&\& { echo \" /' \
    | sed 's/#++/\"; return; }/' \
    > $tmpfile
  source $tmpfile
  rm $tmpfile
}
```

(As a side note, turns out the `&` represents the input substitution in BSD sed.)

Results:

```
$ my_function --help
  Usage : hello <arg1> <arg2> 

$ my_function 
  I'm doing something great.
  and I'm totally self documented.
```